# How to expire token for user in token based authentication for Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

Recently I created **token based authentication** for my Web API project following an [Article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1187872/Token-Based-Authentication-for-Web-API-where-Legac) here I am able to create the token and able to validate the token as well. But when user logged out we are removing the token from user device, if the user saved the token before we remove that token, it still valid until it reaches the expiration time, which leads less security for the API

**Can any once suggest how can I expire the the issued token.** (as we have huge user database we are not storing any tokens in database.)

Comment: This post describes the problem and possible approaches. Keep token lifetimes short, refresh when needed, possibly maintain a 'token revocation list' in some sort of fast access store - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23089839/1538039

Answer (score 1):

```
You can clear cookies and entire session if exists any !


Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();

 Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252339/owin-authentication-expire-current-token-and-remove-cookie